# How to query "not contains" in ArcGIS Server REST API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, spatial-query

I want to query data that is not in a specified polygon in ArcGIS Server Rest API. 
How can I achieve this like below image?

[image]

Comment: I think this could be done using Spatial relationship : "Relation". You then need to provide the relationParam string using Shape Comparison Language.

Comment: Thanks @nef001 Is there any kind of working example or references that show the concepts?

Comment: Reference here: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/40de6491-9b2d-440d-848b-2609efcd46b1.htm#SpatialRelate

Comment: This might work for NOT contains:  '* * T * * T T T *'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You could use **Relation** function in ArcGIS Server REST API

In order to query data that is not in a specified geometry in ArcGIS Server REST API, you should choose `Relation` in Spatial Relationship options and consider the following `Relation` parameter by means of not contains in you're spatial query:

**Relation:** FFTFFT***

Like this image:

[image: ArcGIS Relation function]